# showing overlay/loading image on click of button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, jquery

I am working on asp.net page. This page has a search button and grid view inside an ajax update panel. Gridview has a button in each row which causes a post back. I want to show an overlay /loading image at the top of page when a search button is clicked before gridview is loaded/reloaded so that user can see that data is loading and user can not click search button again. I tried using ajax updateprogress but that is triggered when gridview row buttons are clicked. I want the overlay image to appear only on click of search button. Is there any Jquery plugin available for this functionality or we can customize ajax update progress control ?

Comment: `$.ajaxStart()` function will do or you need something else?

Comment: how to use $ajaxstart () in this case ?

Comment: `$(document).ajaxStart(function(){//some stuff});`. The function will be called each time an ajax call is made.

Comment: @DotnetSparrow take a look at the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16977939/975520

Answer (score 1):

You can include in your page the [`jQuery.blockUI`](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/) plugin, it from the docs:

> Lets you simulate synchronous behavior when using AJAX, without
>   locking the browser. When activated, it will prevent user activity
>   with the page (or part of the page) until it is deactivated. BlockUI
>   adds elements to the DOM to give it both the appearance and behavior
>   of blocking user interaction.

You activate it using:

```
$.blockUI({ message: '<h1><img src="busy.gif" /> Just a moment...</h1>' });
```

and deactivate with:

```
$.unblockUI();
```

You can use it in two ways:

### FIRST

Handle the `beginRequest` and `endRequest` events of the ms ajax `PageRequestManager` and use blockUI in these events.

Example code:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.instance.add_beginRequest(beginRequestHandler);
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.instance.add_endRequest(endRequestHandler);

function beginRequestHandler(sender, args){
    $.blockUI({ message: '<h1><img src="busy.gif" /> Just a moment...</h1>' });
}

function endRequestHandler(sender, args){
    $.unblockUI();
}
```

### SECOND

You can bind and handle [`ajax global events`](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/) fired when every ajax call starts, complete

```
$(document).bind("ajaxStart", function() {
    $.blockUI({ message: '<h1><img src="busy.gif" /> Just a moment...</h1>' });
}).bind("ajaxStop", function() {
    $.unblockUI();
});
```

I successfully used the second solution, but in your case using update panels you can give a try at first too.